# Multi-Layered Blending in 3D

Tags: xna, render, layer, blend, depth

I'm using XNA 4.0 and I have a layer that I need to blend into a 3D scene. I draw particles to a render target which I then draw. This is necessary in order to create the correct effect with additive blending for particles. I need to be able to blend the layer into the scene at the correct depth. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can specify Depth parameter in SpriteBatch::Draw calls. This one is definetly affecting 2D rendering depth but you could try to gamble with it on 3D. Or just sort you rendering calls order.

Comment: The depth parameter in the draw call is used for sorting the order of the 2d sprites. My rendertarget should have varying depths as it is a 3d render, so I don't think that would work.